# ArrayList reading lines from files and assigning them

Tags: java, file, arraylist

I have created a code that reads from a file, every line is a different book, and each line contains a title and a price. The books file is:

```
    The Hobbit,$15.00
    Purple Cow,$10.00
    Death by Black Hole,$35.00
```

The methods work. But I'm trying to create a method that works like: Enter a budget: 15 and then shsows all the boks under 15 dollars. I've done a part of the searchForPrice method but It doesn't really work out. How could I do it? Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class BookStore {
    private ArrayList<Book> library;
    String Book;

    public BookStore() throws FileNotFoundException {
        library = readBooks("books1.txt");
    }
    public ArrayList<Book> readBooks(String path) {
        ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] arr = line.split(",");
                String title = arr[0];
                double price = Double.parseDouble(arr[1].trim().replace("$",""));//in case has a $
                books.add(new Book(title,price));

            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return books;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        for (Book tempBook : library) {
            result += tempBook.toString() + "\n";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public ArrayList<Book> searchForTitle(String searchString) {
        ArrayList<Book> searchResult = new ArrayList<Book>();
        for (Book currentBook : library) {
            if ((currentBook.getTitle()).indexOf(searchString) != -1)
                searchResult.add(currentBook);
        }
        searchResult.trimToSize();
        return searchResult;
    }

    //get lowest price book
    public Book lowestPrice() {
        Book lowestPrice = library.get(0);
        for (Book book : library) {
            if (book.getPrice() < lowestPrice.getPrice()) {
                lowestPrice = book;
            }
        }
        return lowestPrice;
    }

    //bookslessthanthenumbertheyenter
    public ArrayList<Book> searchForPrice(double searchdouble) {
        ArrayList<Book> searchPrice = new ArrayList<Book>();
        for (Book currentBook : library) {
            if ((currentBook.getPrice()).Double.parseDouble.indexOf(searchdouble) != -1)
                searchPrice.add(currentBook);
        }
        searchPrice.trimToSize();
        return searchPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make this `if ((currentBook.getPrice()).Double.parseDouble.indexOf(searchdouble) != -1)` like this -> `if(currentBook.getPrice() < searchdouble)`

Comment: `but It doesn't really work out`  - so what does it do? What debugging have you done?. Did you verify the prices in your Book objects? Did you display the values you are comparing as you iterate through all the books? Don't assume you data or logic is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Does this loop even compile:

```
for (Book currentBook : library) {
    if ((currentBook.getPrice()).Double.parseDouble.indexOf(searchdouble) != -1)
        searchPrice.add(currentBook);
}
```

In the `Book` class you store the price as `double`, so no need for conversion, just compare the price of each book with `searchdouble`:

```
for (Book currentBook : library) {
    if (currentBook.getPrice() < searchdouble)
        searchPrice.add(currentBook);
}
```

Also why do you need:

```
searchPrice.trimToSize();
```

since you did not declare any initial capacity?

Comment: (1+) for the simple double primitive comparison.

Comment: It is simple and I just can't see how would OP get this code `(currentBook.getPrice()).Double.parseDouble.indexOf(searchdouble) != -1`

Answer (score 0):

In Java the best way to compare Doubles would be with the function provided by the Double class **compare**.

So the code would look like this.

`if (Double.compare(currentBook.getPrice(), searchdouble) <= 0)`

The function compare will return 0 if they are both equal, -1 if the first is lower and 1 if it's higher.